# React useState, useEffect not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a use case that I'd like to solve it with React hooks, but it's not working as I expected.

- Expectation: Not on top will be shown on scrolling down and will disappear when scrolling back on top of the document.
- Current: Not on top shown on scrolling down but not disappear when scrolling back on top of the document.
  Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/wkroy1r2xl

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you check for `isHeaderMoved` inside the scroll handler?

Comment: minor: put `handleScroll`'s body into `useCallback` so it will be created just once. By now function is re-created but new version is not used anywhere(since `useEffect` runs just once due to `[]` in arguments)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The component adds the event listener once: only on mount. At that time, it adds the `handleScroll` listener that is "captured" with that specific `isHeaderMoved` value at that specific point in time. Whenever the page is scrolled, the callback that will be called is the one with that initial `isHeaderMoved` value. The current code basically calls `handleScroll` with `false` over and over.

In short, you need to add `isHeaderMoved` as a dependency to the effect. You should also move the `handleScroll` listener inside the effect, so its dependencies can be tracked more properly by the hooks eslint plugin.

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const handleScroll = () => {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
          if (!isHeaderMoved) {
            setIsHeaderMoved(true)
          }
        } else if (isHeaderMoved) {
          setIsHeaderMoved(false)
        }
      }

      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
      }
    },
    [isHeaderMoved],
  )
```

Refer to these sections from Dan Abromov's posts on the subject (which have examples that can explain it better than I could):

- https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-event-handlers
- https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-effects
- https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#moving-functions-inside-effects

It's worth going through the whole post to understand things fully, if you have the time.

---

From skyboxer's comment, it occurred to me that this would also work, but I'll keep all of the above for informational purposes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setIsHeaderMoved(window.pageYOffset > 0)
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same annoying problem once

try adding a key prop on the component when it is created in the parent code

```
<yourcomponent key="some_unique_value" />
```

This is because in most cases, especially when your component is reused, it may usually re-render only with some changes instead of actually creating it again when you reuse it, based on the way it's created, Hence the `useEffect` is not going to be called. eg inside Switch, Router, loops, conditionals...

So adding a key will prevent this from happening. If it is in a loop, you need to make sure each element is unique, maybe by including the index `i` in the key if you can't find any better unique key.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you have to pass the `window.pageYOffset` or `isHeaderMoved` to the `useEffect` to fire it in every time it changes, if you left it `[]` it'll fire once.

```js
  useEffect(
    () => {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      };
    },
    [isHeaderMoved]
  );
```

I think you also can use `useRef()` to do this.

Comment: is there any need to reattach listeners on `window.pageYOffset` changed? I believe it works fine without that(there are just extra checks like `if(isHeaderMoved)` that break the flow).

Comment: `useEffect` doesn't "watch" for changes in values. It only compares them during renders, so passing a value that isn't a part of react's data flow (state, props, or values that derive from them) will yield unexpected results.